# Pandas sorting based on two paired columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have two columns, "before" and "after". We'll just call them `Bf` and `Af` here. Based on many other attached columns, they have been ranked as follows:

```
Bf  Af
3   5
0   2
1   4
5   3
2   0
4   1
```

Now, the way they need to be sorted is

```
Bf  Af
0*  2
2   0
-----
1*  4
4   1
-----
3*  5
5   3
```

So, going through `Bf`, the lowest value is 0. So we set 0 on top. So the top pair is now 0-2, and the reverse order 2-0 must follow right after.

Then we move on to the next before-after pair, which is 1-4, as 1 is the lowest, and we've already sorted 2 from `Bf`. The reverse is 4-1, which follows right after.

And finally, the next value to sort in `Bf` is 3-5, with the reverse 5-3 right after.

Does anybody have an idea of how to sort this?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
df.reindex(pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values,1)).sort_values([0,1]).index)
Out[444]: 
   Bf  Af
1   0   2
4   2   0
2   1   4
5   4   1
0   3   5
3   5   3
```